# git recover single file that was deleted during a merge

Tags: git, repository, branch

I'm  currently in branch 'foo'. I just ran `git merge master`. Only problem is there was a certain file in foo that I wanted to keep. Is there a way to get it back but keep all the other changes from merge master?

Comment: `git merge` won't clobber a file unless its unchanged in the working tree and there is an change to bring in from the other branch. For clarity, did the merge complete successfully and you want the old version from your branch, or did the merge generate conflicts and you want the resolved version to look like your branch's previous version?

Comment: Yes, the merge was successful. I wanted the old version of the file.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
git checkout HEAD -- filename
```

This will roll your fileback one commit. If you want to go back further to a specific commit, you can use a commit hash or append ^N to the end of the HEAD keyword, e.g. `HEAD^2`.

Comment: Or if the merge is not yet complete (due to conflicts), just git checkout filename.

Comment: @ceretullis: if it's due to conflicts in the file in question you will need `git checkout --ours filename`.

Comment: I actually ended up finding this elsewhere but used a commit hash instead of HEAD^1 ... thanks!

Comment: @"Charles Bailey" yup, left that out.

Comment: I don't know if this used to be correct, but a single rollback is at `HEAD^` (or branchname instead of HEAD) and further commits backward are `HEAD~2` (ie. HEAD~n)

Comment: if he didnt commit his last changes HEAD will make him rollback to the last commit; if he didn't change anything he is at HEAD already. HEAD^n is to rollback further

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to correct the problem from the current situation, but you may want to look at `git merge -s ours`. The docs are [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

A workflow would be

1. Create branch `a` from `master`
2. Do a custom change in branch `a` that you will not want to merge back into `master`
3. Check out `master` and `git merge -s ours a`
4. Check out `a` and continue working and committing.

Now when you merge with master, the custom changes in step 2 will be ignored.